# Document write and open in same window

Tags: javascript

I have problem with writing to document:

```
NewWindow.document.write("Hi, this is test");
NewWindow = window.open("pages/Example.html","_self");
```

And page is blank. If I use

```
NewWindow.document.write("Hi, this is test");
NewWindow = window.open("pages/Example.html","displayWindow");
```

It works but I want rewrite content of current page.

```
var NewWindow = window.open("pages/Example.html","_self");
NewWindow.document.write("Hi, this is test");
```

I want create object window, write to him and then show.

Comment: Check your console.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, your problem is the order you're executing those functions.
How do you write to a page if the page isn't there?

```
var NewWindow = window.open("pages/Example.html","_self");
NewWindow.document.write("Hi, this is test");
```

Comment: Yes, but I want first write text to document and then show.. This code rewrite content with new page but not writes "Hi, this is test"

Comment: @Peter3 That doesn't make sense, you can't write content to a page that doesn't exist...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'll explain badly. I want something like: var NewWindow = Window(pages/Example.html") // example

NewWindow.document.write("Hi, this is test");
and then Show
NewWindow = window.open("pages/Example.html","_self");

Comment: Create object window, write to him, and then show with all content

Comment: @Peter3, you can't. What exactly is the purpose of that? If data is obtained or processed before the window open then there are other ways of doing so. What you want however can't be done.